# How about recently viewed question in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, implementation

I what to ask you about recently viewed question in one panel at right side. Basically sometimes, after viewing a question, you may realize that you needs to review it again. So, in that case there would be some kind of panel there.

How about this?

[image]

Comment: Indeed! Sometimes I look at a question, then click-back to the question list, and do something. And then something comes to my mind regarding this question, and it's hard to find it quickly again without using the search option.

Comment: @BartoszKP exactly what i am trying to say +1 :)

Comment: @BartoszKP - your browser doesn't have a history feature?

Comment: @Oded Yes it does :) I'm not saying that it's a big problem :-) But I agree with OP that such a link on main SO site would be very convenient.

Comment: @BartoszKP - taking dev resources to reproduce a common browser feature? And put it in a spot where more important stuff should be shown? I'll have to disagree on that one ;)

Comment: @Oded Probably you're right :) I still like the idea though.

Comment: @Oded not history feature but there should be atleast something that i can see which question i have read. I have problem many times 
i read question goes to another suddenly i found answer in first one so i lost there

Comment: With a use case, additionally, for when I viewed four questions this morning, obliterated my history with other stuff, and want to review those questions again this afternoon. Browser history won't help me there.

Comment: Oh! it will be useless if i ask for whole day history one hrs may be :O??

Comment: @BartoszKP do you always see question in tabs?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit- amazing question...

Comment: @dholakiyaankit I'm using FF, there seems to be no other option to view anything.

Comment: It exists in a hidden feature. Ctrl + Shift + T

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd That just brings u pictures of cats in jumpers for me...

Comment: @JMK Hum.. must be broken.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd That doesn't sound broken to me.  Who doesn't like pictures of cats in jumpers?

Comment: @Servy I'm more of a dog man. (Can I be banned for this ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather not have a recently viewed questions list/widget on the right side, where the tags are. There is already enough on the right side. It has caused me some extra work when I add ignore tags and having to scroll up/down the page too much because of the careers box. Adding recently reviewed questions there would make this problem even worse.

I'd be more than fine with recently reviewed questions going into the profile section of your account. So you could get to it there.

If your idea does come to fruition though, I'd seriously recommend limiting it to the last 3 or or 5 questions reviewed. With the option to view more in your profile.

Comment: that's what exactly i want to say to you it not necessary that it must be on a right side but it can be any where but it should be

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to see a recent history of questions you had voted on (or one of their answers) instead of that one closed question you visited out of curiosity.

What if every time you voted on a question or an answer, it kept it in a list so that you could go view them at a later date! ;)

[image: vote tab]

[image: votes]